# NPM build script fails on decorators (webpack, production)

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm running an npm build script to bundle and minify my code:

```
"build": "rimraf dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.config.prod.js"
```

I don't know how to get rid of this error. Only getting it in the production build, works fine in dev mode.

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Decorators are not officially supported yet in 6.x pending a proposal update.
However, if you need to use them you can install the legacy decorators transform with...
```

My .babelrc looks like this:

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1", "stage-0"],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "babel-plugin-webpack-alias",
            {
                "config": "webpack.config.dev.js",
                "findConfig": true
            }
        ],
        ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
    ]
}
```

My webpack.config.prod.js looks like this:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                include: [
                    path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
                    path.join(__dirname, 'server/shared'),
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'stage-1', 'react'],
                    plugins: [
                        'transform-decorators-legacy',
                    ],
                },
            },
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed the plugin?

Comment: Yup, I have installed it.

Comment: Have you tried running babel by itself not through webpack?

Comment: Try setting the transfor decorators legacy plugin the first one in the plugin array. I think they execute in order.

Comment: Changing the order didn't work. I'm using Babel in development (and it works) but need to get Webpack working with it in order to minify my code for production, Jared.